# Objective c extracting a number from a long string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like this

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;"> 
 <a data-mce-href="NewdownloadSingle? 
   db_value=Test_2.jpg%23ms_attach_delimiter%23784123161&id=102003&proc=1085821&processInstanceId=1085821&attach_seq=203&oper=R" 
   href="javascript:void(0)"  
   onclick="parent.openRTFAttachment(784123161,link);" 
   title="Test_2.jpg" alt="Test_2.jpg" target="_blank">Test_2.jpg 
 </a> 
</p>
```

I want to find the number that is present between parent.openRTFAttachment(784123161,link)

I want to extract 784123161 how can I do it in objective C

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression or you could use an `NSScanner`. Either of these solutions will scan through the string looking for some pattern to start and allow you to extract a section of the string between there and a defined end pattern. This will give you the string for the number which you can then use / convert.

From your comments it seems like you can just do a simple string replace:

```
NSString *str = @"This is your string";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Source number"
                                     withString:@"Destination number"];
```

Comment: I can have multiple occurrences of openRTFAttachment(784123161,link) i would want to replace each of them with some other number

Comment: Is the number always the same? Are the numbers unique in the text? Would you replace the number with another of the same length? It's usually best to ask the real question instead of asking about your idea of a solution that you haven't implemented...

Comment: The number is the same in all but i will not replace it with a number of same length

Comment: Sounds like you can just use simple string find and replace API.

Comment: Can u give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
NSString *searchedString = @"<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0pt;\">    <a data-mce-href=\"NewdownloadSingle?    db_value=Test_2.jpg%23ms_attach_delimiter%23784123161&id=102003&proc=1085821&processInstanceId=1085821&attach_seq=203&oper=R\"    href=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"parent.openRTFAttachment(784123161,link);\"title=\"Test_2.jpg\" alt=\"Test_2.jpg\" target=\"_blank\">Test_2.jpg</a></p>";

NSRange  searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
NSString *pattern = @"RTFAttachment[(]([0-9]+)";
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range: searchedRange];

for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    NSLog(@"match: %@", [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]]);
    NSLog(@"RTFAttachment number: %@", [searchedString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

this extract number from parent.openRTFAttachment

Answer (score 0):

it might be overcomplicated, but does the job for you:

```
NSString *_string = @"<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0pt;\"> <a data-mce-href=\"NewdownloadSingle? db_value=Test_2.jpg%23ms_attach_delimiter%23784123161&id=102003&proc=1085821&processInstanceId=1085821&attach_seq=203&oper=R\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\"  onclick=\"parent.openRTFAttachment(784123161,link);\" title=\"Test_2.jpg\" alt=\"Test_2.jpg\" target=\"_blank\">Test_2.jpg </a> </p> ";
```

after you have the original string you could do this:

```
NSError *_error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\(\\s*(\\d*)\\s*," options:0 error:&_error];
NSArray *_matches = [_regExp matchesInString:_string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, _string.length)];
NSString *_yourNumber = nil;
if (_matches.count > 0) {
    NSTextCheckingResult *_result = [_matches firstObject];
    if (_result.numberOfRanges > 1) {
        _yourNumber = [_string substringWithRange:[_result rangeAtIndex:1]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", _yourNumber);
```

then on the console that will appear clearly:

```
`784123161`
```

---

*NOTE: you might need to refine the initial pattern if the source's format is changed. if you have multiple occurrences in the original input string it finds the very first one for you.*